# Error while loading YAML file

Tags: yaml, ansible

I try to run this piece of code

```
---
- hosts: my-host
  - vsphere_guest:
    vcenter_hostname: vcenter.mydomain.local
    username: myuser
    password: mypass
    guest: newvm001
    vmware_guest_facts: yes
```

but I keep getting this error.

> > ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
>
> The error appears to have been in
>   '/Users/Desktop/Ansible/createvms.yml': line 3, column 3,
>   but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ```
> - hosts: my-host
>   - vsphere_guest:   ^ here
> ```

Can someone please help explain what is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can try. :-) When you write `- hosts: my-host`, this starts a new list containing a dict with one key-value pair (`hosts`, which is set to a string value). Then the YAML parser sees `- vsphere_guest:` indented one level and it's not quite sure what to do with it. It can't nest it under `hosts` because that's already set to a string. It can't start a new list because it's indented. So it fails.

I think what you really want is something like this:

```
---
- hosts: my-host
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: vcenter.mydomain.local
        username: myuser
        password: mypass
        guest: newvm001
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
```